# Cannot use dot2tex environment due to undefined control sequence

Tags: errors, pdftex, dot2tex, dot2texi

I am trying to execute the following example from the dot2texi manual, by running `pdflatex --shell-escape pres.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[neato,mathmode]
    digraph G {
    node [shape="circle"];
    a_1 -> a_2 -> a_3 -> a_4 -> a_1;
    }
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pres.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/dot2texi/dot2texi.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moreverb/moreverb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
 (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
topaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
shapes.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
shapes.geometric.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.geomet
ric.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
shapes.misc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.misc.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
shapes.symbols.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.symbol
s.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
shapes.arrows.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.arrows
.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
shapes.callouts.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.callou
ts.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
shapes.multipart.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.multip
art.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
arrows.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.tex))
(./pres.aux) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Undefined control sequence.
\dottotexverbatimwrite ... \openout \verbatim@out 
                                                  #1 \BeforeStream \let \do ...
l.6 \begin{dot2tex}[neato,mathmode]

? No pages of output.
Transcript written on pres.log.
```

If I run the command without `--shell-escape` it gives me the same error, except that it also tells me I should use `--shell-escape`. I have checked and I have the following available:

- xkeyval latex package
- moreverb latex package
- pgf latex package
- pstricks latex package
- graphviz package
- dot2tex package

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: It compiles on my environment. I have TeX Live 2017, perhaps you could try upgrading

Comment: I'd guess there is some sort of version mismatch since some files come from texmf–dist and others from texmf-site. (I'm not familiar with the latter.)

Comment: Can you look in the log file for the version of `moreverb.sty`?

Comment: @egreg `pres.log
29:(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moreverb/moreverb.sty
30:Package: moreverb 2008/06/03 v2.3a `more' verbatim facilities`

Comment: @Moriambar I have updated to texlive-2017 deleted all the trace files and recompiled now, and I get the same error. the moreverb version has also not changed.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `-shell-escape` and not `--shell-escape` ?

Comment: Your file compile perfectly on my box. Probably some of your system files  have to be updated..  I  added \listfiles to get the  versions of called files. Do compare :http://ix.io/2cYF